# Logout in Kafka After Creating KafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I can access to kafka with client/secret like:

```
   KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(with below properties));

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("security.protocol", SecurityProtocol.SASL_PLAINTEXT.name());
    p.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", SaslMechanism.OAUTH_BEARER.getType());
    p.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required " + configOptions + " ;");
```

it works very well but when I completed my task, I want to `logout` somehow. Otherwise, it continue to fetch access-token. Is there a way to do it?